# How to detect when project is run by Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have a .net Core 3.1 Web API solution, using EF Core for the database. When I execute `Add-Migration` to generate database migrations, the tool runs the startup project. I want to skip some code that executes when the startup project starts (it will not impact the migration generation). Is there a way to tell, in the project code, that it has been launched from the EF tool?

Comment: I do it [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/MintPlayerContext.cs#L45). I run the migration commands from the Data project. Note that the order of the constructors matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Entity Framework Core 7, they've added the static flag [EF.InDesignTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.isdesigntime?view=efcore-7.0) that you can check to know if you are in design time:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (EF.DesignTime)
          return;

        // other stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While not completly reliable, a workarround could be to use `#if DEBUG` directive :

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        // Debug mode: stop here
        return;
        #endif

        // other stuff
    }
```